# How to disable debug logs (app and revel both) in app.conf file of revel framework?

Tags: go, revel

I want to disable debug logs and want other logs to put in a file(logfile). I have tried following two snippets. But it doesnt work as expected.

```
log.all.filter.module.app = logfile
log.all.filter.module.revel = logfile
log.debug.filter.module.app = off
log.debug.filter.module.revel = off


log.all.output = logfile
log.debug.output = off
```

Going through the revel log documentation (http://revel.github.io/manual/logging.html), they have mentioned that order of the log is significant but it isnt working in this case it seems. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are seeing is debug output from the proxy. When running the revel application from the command line like

```
 revel run myapp
```

The proxy starts up in debug mode (meaning you will see lots of debug messages), after the application has started the log should be configured to what is set in the app.conf

Also there may be an assumption that off is an active handler, so it would discard the data, unfortunately the handlers are "or"ed logically together, not "and"ed so setting all outputs to one handler then turning one off does not affect the logger set to all